# SpringBoot reject all request if some header parms are not there even if we don't include them in specific requests

Tags: spring-boot, java-11, spring-restcontroller

An example of that is below. I am not using associateId, firstName, lastName and galleryId but I want this request to be rejected if they are not present (Below code works for this). But is there a common place where we can set it for all request by default and not have to repeat the below code for all request?

```
@ApiOperation("Delete Project")
@DeleteMapping(value = "{projectId}")
public void deleteProject(
        @ApiParam(value = "Project Id to be deleted", required = true) @PathVariable String projectId,
        @RequestHeader("associateId") String associateId,
        @RequestHeader("associateFirstName") String firstName,
        @RequestHeader("associateLastName") String lastName,
        @RequestHeader("galleryId") String galleryId) {
    pjs.deleteProject(projectId);
}
```

I have lot of endpoints and only few use all 4 header variables but I want all request to have access to them even if they are not using them.

Comment: you may create a filter that will check the required parameters for the request

Comment: This is what you are looking for https://www.programmersought.com/article/9344637830/